# White Screen of Death in CP After Login

Tags: ee2, white-screen-of-death, focus-lab-master-config, server-migration

I just migrated a site from the development server on MediaTemple (gs) to the production server on EngineHosting (shared). The front-end of the site displays fine (except some random images aren't displaying), but I get white-screen of death after logging-in to the control panel. My system folder is above web root and I'm using [Focus Lab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config). Here's what I've tried so far:

- I cleared the cache before migrating.
- I've enabled debugging in config.env.php, index.php, and admin.php, but no errors display.
- I've cleared my .htaccess file.
- I checked that my cache folder has 777 permissions.

Not sure what else to try at this point, though I suspect Master Config is the culprit. Suggestions?

EE 2.5.3

**UPDATE:** After suggestions from @Tyssen and @jackmcpickle, I removed Master Config, which revealed an extension error. So I disabled extensions via config.php and the Control Panel is displaying. But if I go to the extensions page, only the 1st party extensions show up, so I can't enable/disable 3rd party extensions one by one. What could be causing that?

**UPDATE 2:** The reason I couldn't see my 3rd party extensions is because my `third_party_path` config var was wrong. Unfortunately, once I fixed the path, I got WSoD in the CP again, even with extensions disabled. So we're back to square one again.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the master config and running with EE's default config files?

Comment: @Tyssen After doing that I got an error about an extension, so I disabled extensions in config.php and the control panel showed up. The trouble is that it doesn't seem to be one specific extension causing the problem, so I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the phpinfo output on both the dev and production server to see if there is any difference in php version / mode / main settings which might shed some light?

Comment: @tidy Is there anything specific you suggest I look for? There are quite a lot of settings and I don't know what most of them do...

Comment: You say you got an error about an extension, so was it not that one particular one causing the problem?

Comment: @Tyssen That doesn't appear to be the case. The initial error was for Better Workflow, so I disabled Better Workflow but then got the exact same set of errors for Zoo Triggers. Disabled Zoo Triggers, then got the same errors for Freebie, etc. etc.

Comment: What are the exact error messages you get? They should help pinpoint the problem. Re PHP differences, is the PHP version the same on both hosts and is it running in the same mode (apache module or CGI) on both?

Comment: Were you getting an error saying that the extension couldn't be loaded? If so, it sounds like the path to your third_party folder might be incorrect.

Comment: @tyssen An incorrect third_party path _was_ the cause of the php errors. However, ironically, after fixing the paths, I get WSoD again, even with extensions disabled. I think the problem might be EngineHosting shared accounts and having the system folder above web root.

Comment: @tyssen Nope, moved my system folder to the web root but still getting WSoD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After uselessly beating my head against the wall on this, I just decided to clear all the files from the server, drop the database, and re-upload everything.

Now it works fine.

Thank you, thank you, THANK YOU to everyone for all of your excellent suggestions, and I'm really sorry for totally mangling this question.

Comment: kgrote, EngineHosting does support system folder above web root, in the normal way. I moved to this arrangement many months ago, and it works just fine. Probably just needs a fresh set of eyes...

Comment: On the fix by clean slate and fresh uploads, I've led many a person through those -- there are real problems with many FTP clients, and you can very easily end up with mangled files. I would think this to be a solved issue about 20 years ago, but quite apparently it is not. You just got caught yourself this time. I don't know any way to handle it but a steady hand, in the sense that EE pretty dependably works, in standard base configurations.

Answer (score 24):

Most WSoDs are caused by a PHP error that haults processing combined with configuration that prevents the error from being shows in the browser.

The fastest way to debug white screen errors is to turn on logging and startup errors. The instructions below assume you are running under Apache with an Override setting that will allow php_flag and php_value directions in your .htaccess file.

**Of course, before changing any files make sure you have a backup of the database and files!**

1. Create a directory in your home directory named log and make it writeable:

   ```
   $ cd ~
   $ mkdir log
   $ chmod -R 777 log
   ```
2. Create an .htaccess file in the root of your project with these lines in it:

   ```
   php_flag display_errors 1
   php_flag display_startup_errors 1
   php_value error_reporting 30719
   php_value error_log /home/USER/log/PROJECT.log
   php_flag log_errors 1
   ```
3. I'd recommend putting the following line at the top of your front controllers (your root level /system/index.php, /index.php and /admin.php) so you can see what requests cause what log output:

   ```
   error_log($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . ' ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : ''));
   ```
4. While making the request that crashes EE, watch the log file with:

   ```
   $ tail -f /home/USER/log/PROJECT.log
   ```

The htaccess file does a few things:

1. Sets error reporting to the current `E_ALL` value (you cannot use constants in .htaccess).
2. You should see any syntax errors - that's what `display_startup_errors` does
3. If the code turns off `display_errors` anywhere (pretty common when you are using a lot of third party code) you should still see the errors in the log.

If this doesn't work, look in your codebase for the following things. [ack](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/ack-2.00a01/Ack.pm) works best for this - it's like grep on steroids - but you can instead use your text editor's Find in Files functionality to search through a local copy if you have FTP-only access.

Stuff to check for (each of these is a call that may or may not have arguments, just search for each word listed and take the recommended action):

1. `@include`, `@require` - any of these will ignore syntax errors in the included files. Change these to not have the @ sign so that errors inside them will show up. I believe there is still at least one reference to @require in the Extensions.php file, although this might have been removed finally.
2. `@eval` - less likely than the above but would also ignore syntax errors. This shouldn't be used by core EE but could be used by add-ons. Change to not have the @ sign.
3. `exit`, `die` - obvious probably, but make sure there is an echo before any of these so that you can see which one caused the output to end (resulting in a White screen).
4. `log_errors` - see if someone is turning off error logging for some reason.
5. `error_reporting` - comment out all of these in third-party add-ons as well as the core. Any of these will disable error reporting to not match the settings provided above.
6. `ini_set('display_errors', '0')` or `ini_set('display_errors', 0)` or `ini_set('display_errors', false)`- comment out all of these as well

If this still doesn't work, you can use a PHP debugger to trace through the code (such as XDebug and one of the many debugging GUI front-ends available such as PhpStorm), or add `error_log()` and `error_log(print_r($something, true))` calls to write things to the log. This is a lot better than print or echo because it can't be erased or output buffered and gets written instantly to the log file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, it's a shared hosting plan so I can't SSH into it. I tried adding a log directory above web root and modifying the .haccess code you provided, but that resulted in a 500 error.

Your paragraph about .ack is totally incomprehensible to me, I have no idea what to do with that information. :)

Comment: It sounds like a lot of your issues stem from things you can't do because you are on a shared account, but your host should be able to help you get those things accomplished. I'd contact your host and ask them to help you solve the problem or accomplish the things being recommended here.

Comment: You basically want to look for those function calls in your code base - you can do this on a local copy using your text editor's Find In Files. I'll update the text to indicate this.

Comment: Also note that this assumes you are running under Apache with an Override setting that allows php_flag and php_value directions in your .htaccess file... if you aren't, and since you have FTP only there is probably a good chance you are not, the logging stuff won't work.

Answer (score 3):

When I have had a WSoDs in the past it has often been due to third party extensions failing.

Try turning off extensions in config.php and work your way back from there. Also, make sure you third-party extensions are up to date.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Scratch that, disabling extensions in _Master Config_ didn't work for some reason, but when I removed Master Config and disabled extensions via config.php, it did. Now the issue is that it doesn't appear to be one specific extension causing the problem, so I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: When you delete an extension it should throw an error for the missing extension once you have logged in and it is required. just try going through each one and prefixing each one with a "." to make it hidden. Then if it is required you can rename it back.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a memory issue, add

```
# Increase PHP Memory
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

to your .htaccess on the root of the html folder.

Comment: Hi & welcome, could you expand on this answer a bit? Perhaps about how to tell if it's a memory related issue, or other ways you could increase the PHP `memory_limit`? Aim to make it as useful to later readers as to the OP...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is possible on EngineHosting, but could you try re-booting your server instance?  I've had this issue happen before while migrating sites and to fix it I just had to restart apache and everything worked great.

Comment: It's a shared plan, so I don't think I can re-boot.

Comment: Can you clarify why restarting Apache solved this issue? I cannot think of anything in ExpressionEngine that would ever require restarting Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Before going crazy I'd also try clearing your browser cookies.

Comment: Good suggestion, but sadly it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which version of EE you're using or what add-ons but from experience a common cause of this has been Image Sizer. The specific problem being large files causing out of memory errors. There have been occasions where it has caused a problem even when the files in question are not being directly accessed.

Comment: Actually, I _did_ say what version of EE I'm using, and I'm not using Image Sizer.

Comment: You did! Sorry, my mistake. I totally missed that!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by myself today removing expressionengine/cache and then watching the folder on login. 
Turns out it was a devotee accessory failing due to a disabled php function. But I could see it creating a folder in cache.

Check/disable your accessories and extensions to check they are not the issue. 90% of the time they are when moving servers.

EE version 2.5.5

Answer (score -1):

white screen usually points toward a memory issue.

Comment: What do you suggest I do about it?