# Control Panel - Strange WSOD Issue

Tags: control-panel, white-screen-of-death

Yesterday I went live with a site from my development server (WAMP) to my production server (LAMP).  I made all of my changes to paths and DB, and while the site was coming up, I was having some issues getting into the CP.  I think it was a URL issue as the domain name under which I was developing was different than the live site.  I finally got it straightened out and was able to get logged in.

Somewhere along the line, I must have made an adjustment that then broke things.  The front end of the site still works, but I’m now getting the dreaded WSoD when accessing the CP.  Very strange since it was workign fine.  So somewhere I must have made an adjustment that broke things.  Retracing my steps hasn't solved anything.  Hopefully the following provides something that triggers an idea.

When logging in, it goes to the authenticate URL, then to the home page URL where it gives me the WSoD.

I've tried altering the URL to see if I could access other parts of the CP.  Here are the results:

- WSoD – any of the add-ons (modules, accessories, extensions, field-types, plugins)
- WSoD – home page
- CAN ACCESS – templates, template manager, snippets, etc.
- CAN ACCESS – area to manage members and groups

I’ve tried to turn on debugging in my admin.php template, as well as the index.php and system/index.php.  Doing so provides no additional information.  I’ve also re-uploaded the files and dropped the DB and imported again.

I spent several hours last night trying everything I could think of.  So any help is very much appreciated.  The answer is probably in front of me, but my head is hurting from banging it on the wall!

Comment: You may find some helpful tips in the answers on this post http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/98/white-screen-of-death-in-cp-after-login

Comment: Thanks - I did look at that page last night, but I'll review it again today with fresh eyes to see if I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I contacted EllisLab Support for assistance - and they were fantastic.  It turns out that I had a second (and possibly older/different) Switchee folder in my third_party add-ons folder (I had one folder "switchee" and another "croxton-Switchee-b813d5b".  As soon as I removed the latter, I was able to log in.  They said that the error was suppressed due to an @ on the include. They would look into removing that for easier debugging in the future.

The thing that is still strange to me is that my local dev site still works just fine (with the duplicate folder).  But I'm not going to spend any more time trying to figure out why.  It's working!

Thanks again to Alex, and especially Anna for your continued attempts to assist!

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to start your migration over. Move files and database freshly since things did work when you first moved over.

Then before you log into the CP on the production server, clear your browser cache and cookies, then add this to your config.php file:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
$config['cookie_path'] = "";
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['admin_session_type'] = "s";
$config['user_session_type'] = "c";
$config['require_ip_for_login'] = "n";
$config['require_ip_for_posting'] = "n"; 
$config['secure_forms'] = "n";
```

Comment: Thanks Anna.  Not sure what  part of that was the problem, but after deleting and re-uploading everything, I was able to get back into the CP.  Odd.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, so I spoke too soon.  I hadn't added the information to the config.php file because I was able to get in without it.  However, after my session expired, now I can't get in again.  If I add the above to my config.php, then it freezes on the "authenticate" part.  If I remove it, it just keeps bouncing me to the login.  Grrr....

Comment: Try adding in each line by line.

Comment: And clear cache and cookies.

Comment: I did that last night, and the only difference it made was whether it froze on the authenticate part, or just kicked me back to the login screen.  The only thing that i can think of is this - when I was developing the site locally, I used a domain name originalsite.com.  Before we went live they wanted to switch it to newsite.com.  I'm not sure if somewhere, somehow, that is what is confusing things?  So I started a completely fresh install with the newsite.com and will see what happens....

Comment: OK, update on this issue.  I started from complete scratch and set up a new 2.5.5 installation (the other was 2.5.3).  I recreated the channels and all information, blah blah blah.  I uploaded everything to the server.  The site is working and I was plugging away in the CP, updating some of the content.  I went to access the add-ons (which I had been in several times) and suddenly I get the WSoD AGAIN, and now I can't get anywhere in the frickin' control panel!  My local WAMP install is working fine, by the way.

Comment: So I contacted the host to see if they could see anything more on their end.  They experience the same problem when trying to log in, but it's not creating any additional error messages in the logs.  I have seen other WSoD posts that relate to PHP memory issues.  My hosting account is set to 128M.  I am not sure if it could be related to Republic Analytics, which I had set up and enabled shortly before experiencing the issue. However, I am not sure of the best way to remove it via the database (since I can't get into the CP).

Comment: Something to try is to temporarily disable extensions by adding  $config['allow_extensions'] = "n";  to your config.php file. This will tell you if it's a conflict with a specific extension.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it didn't make any difference to the WSoD.  It's really strange that it works fine on my Dev WAMP server.  The only difference I can tell is that I don't have Republic Analytics "running".  It would seem odd that it would cause an issue with the entire CP though.  I'm going to try to upload everything AGAIN and see whether it works without the RA add-on activated.

Comment: Anything in your PHP error logs?

Comment: I had the host look at the logs on their end, and even gave them access to the CP.  They didn't see anything.  The only logs that I have access to (that I can tell) are the "raw access logs", and while I can see my attempts to log in, I don't see anything in there.

Comment: So nothing in the PHP Error logs?

Comment: No, nothing that we could find.  I went through the DB and compared it to the DEV and there isn't anything out of the ordinary.  The sessions list in the DB shows when I try to log in, so it's getting that far.  But I just can't get in.  I even created another Super Admin user and tried logging in with that account, and the same thing happens.  I went through the "system" folder and compared it to my dev install to see if something was missing.  Nothing.  I will probably upload a test version this evening and see what happens.

Comment: I think your best bet now is to contact EllisLab support to have them figure this out for you.

Comment: Hi Anna - just a quick follow-up.  I tried several things today that didn't work.  I just now set up my trial of EE Support and submitted a ticket.  Not sure if you want me to leave this open for an (hopefully) answer?

Comment: Please do post the correct answer back here as a new answer when you get it. Good luck!