# WSoD and Imgsizer Plugin

Tags: plugin, image, white-screen-of-death

Site is running EE 2.1.3 and I'm now getting WSoD on a few of my front-end pages (notably those with imgsizer plugin enabled, the other pages without images are working fine). I've read that it's a memory issue related to trying to generate a thumbnail with Image Sizer plugin (running 2.6.4) in this [related thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12052/white-screen-of-death-with-extensions-enabled-ee-v-1-6-0) but no solutions are offered. I tried upgrading to newer version that's been forked on GitHub but got the same problem. I've also changed the memory allocation to 512M and still no luck. Enabling debugging in index.php yields no PHP errors on the back-end and template files are parsing correctly.

This all started when I got an error message after a member couldn't upload a file (I'm assuming it was too large although I haven't heard back from them yet). The following error came from our server:

[19-Feb-2015 11:24:25 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 17472 bytes) in /home/artdistr/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/imgsizer/pi.imgsizer.php on line 546

Now I'm getting a whole host of problems where paths aren't found (I'll only include one since there's a ton of them) from the server:
Feb 26 12:24:22 2015] [error] [client 69.245.61.229] File does not exist: /home/artdistr/public_html/themes/template_variables, referer: http://www.artdistrictonsantafe.com/system/index.php?S=0&D=cp&C=addons_plugins

Thanks in advance, I'm totally stumped here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer was actually not Image Sizer but CE Image plugin, even though the initial error referenced the imgsizer plugin directory. What was happening was that there wasn't enough server resources to load the images which stopped the other plugins from loading and caused the plugins not to load dynamic files leading to other errors like directories not found.

I went into the `pi.ce_img.php` file and changed line 82 (below comments) from 60 to 256:

```
/* The PHP memory limit.
    This script needs an adequate amount of memory (measured in megabytes) allocated from your server in
    order to work. Generally, 64 should be more than enough. This value can also be overwritten in config.php. */
    private $memory_limit = 256;
```

Obviously this seems like a huge amount of memory resources (I still need to fine tune with server) but the site is loading very fast now on all pages. Hopefully this helps someone else, I could see similar problems arising with other image plugins.