# WCOD in when loging in to Control Panel after moving servers

Tags: control-panel, white-screen-of-death, server-migration

I'm out of ideas here, and posting this as a last resort hopping you can give me some ideas where the problem might lie.

I moved servers recently, and I don't know whether this is a problem that might have caused the issue I'm having now is I didn't clear the cache before exporting all the files (forgot).

But the problem is after moving servers Front End works fine, database works fine. But when I try and login to CP I get WCOD :(

I've increase PHP memory to 128MB that did not seem to fix the issue. Cleared the cache/ cookies on my computer, cleared .htaccess file etc.

[Link to website](http://www.yourpeakstate.com)

I tried looking up online and reading other questions but that didn't seem to do it for me. [This seemed to be most related question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/98/white-screen-of-death-in-cp-after-login)

I'm not asking you to fix this for me but maybe to direct me to the right direction here. As I said this is my last resort :)

ALSO:

When using search functionality in banner I get an error "The search path contains an error. Please contact the system administrator."

Here is Search template code:

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="blog_post|quotes_article" result_page="search/results" no_result_page="search/no-results" where="all" results="15" search_in="everywhere" status="open"}
                <input type="text" name="keywords" id="search-input" placeholder="I'm looking for...">
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Thanks again,

Comment: Well, as to your WCOD issue; there is secretly no WSOD. Turn PHP error reporting alllll the way up and you should get an error on that page: `php error_reporting( E_ALL );`. Make sure your config.php file has that value all the way up; it can be tricky to insert it in the right place to get the reporting.

Comment: Hi @jrothafer just to confirm error_reporting(E_ALL); should it go to config.php top of the file? Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with setting `$debug= 1;` in your /system/index.php

It's most likely an extension.
or try setting this in your config file.
https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#allow-extensions

```
#allow_extensions = 'n'
```

Comment: Hi sorry about late reply, been moving house in the past 2 days.. didn't get a chance to answer. I will try this and keep you updated. Thx